# Salesforce Attachments before/after insert trigger: ContentType field value is not available

Tags: attachment, upload, contenttype

I need to write a trigger in order to prevent users from uploading some predefined file types. (Please note that I don't want to use "File Upload and Download Security" option for some other reason) For this I need to know the "ContentType" fields value.

My problem is, I cannot see ContentType field is pre-populated before or after insert of the trigger execution,

1. Any reason for this?
2. Is there any other approach for this?

Below is a result of the object; (system.debug);

```
Attachment:{Id=null,
 IsDeleted=false,
 ParentId=00318000008H9R8AAK,
 Name=Resume_dertet_retret.HTML,
 IsPrivate=true,
 ContentType=null,
 BodyLength=1908,
 Body=Blob[1908],
 OwnerId=0051300000BffRYAAZ,
 CreatedDate=null,
 CreatedById=null,
 LastModifiedDate=null,
 LastModifiedById=null,
 SystemModstamp=null,
 Description=null}
```

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps this helps: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187992&language=en_US